# How can i add the selected value from a dropdown list to the database?

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin, html-select

I can call the values of the drop down box from the database, but I can't save the selected value in a new row within the database. Can someone please tell me where I'm going wrong?

```
if (isset($_POST["addDestination"]) && $_POST["addDestination"]=="yes")
{
    $countriesName=$_POST["countriesName"];
    $Name=$_POST["Name"];
    $photo=$_POST["photo"];
    $description=$_POST["description"];
    $Airport=$_POST["Airport"];
    $Airport2=$_POST["Airport2"];
    $Airline=$_POST["Airline"];
    $Airline2=$_POST["Airline2"];
    $Airline3=$_POST["Airline3"];
    $Airline4=$_POST["Airline4"];

    $dbQuery= "INSERT INTO destinations VALUES( NULL, '$countriesName', '$Name', '$photo', '$description', '$Airport', '$Airport2', '$Airline', '$Airline2', '$Airline3', '$Airline4')";
    $result= mysql_query($dbQuery,$db);
```

The html code and php code that call the values in from the database is:

```
<form id="addDestination" name="addDestination" method="post" action="addDestination.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="addDestination" value="yes">
    <div id="countriesName" class="info"><span class="formLabel">Country (Please select one of the following)</span><br>
    <?php 
      echo "<p></p>";
      $dbQuery="SELECT Name FROM countries order by name asc";
      $dbResult=mysql_query($dbQuery);
      echo "<select name=\"Name\">";
      while ($dbRow=mysql_fetch_array($dbResult)) {
        $Name=$dbRow["Name"];
        echo "<option value='$Name'>$Name</option>";
      }
      echo "</select>";
      echo "<p> </p>";
    ?>
  </div>
```

When I try to save a selected value, the field in the database stays blank.

Comment: Try running $result= mysql_query($dbQuery,$db) or die(mysql_error()) to see what error it shows. It will help to debug.

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing, which value are your trying to submit into database?

Comment: sorry should have explained better. I want to be able to select the name of a country from the drop down box which i can populate from the countries table in the database but when i select a country to add to the destinations table the field remains blank. I hope this makes sense sorry again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this might be that rather than:

```
$countriesName=$_POST["countriesName"];
```

you may need to use:

```
$countriesName=$_POST["Name"];
```

`"Name"` is the name of your actual HTML select, rather than `"countriesName"` which is the containing div.

Comment: I've also just noticed you already have Name passed in the POST, so you may have to rename your HTML select tag, eg. call it cName and pick that up from the POST variable.